# convert Vue3 Typescript to Vue3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Hi i could you please help me to convert this into javascript in Vue3 thank you

```
import type { App } from 'vue'
import Screenfull from './Screenfull.vue'

const components = [
  Screenfull,
]

const install = (app: App): void => {
  components.forEach(component => {
    app.component(component.name, component)
  })
}

export default install
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plugin loops through a bunch of components and registers them globally, using the `name` property of the component.  So make sure each component registered this way has a `name` property:

*Dashboard.vue*

```html
<template>
  <div>My component</div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'Dashboard'      // ✅ Add this
}
```

Remove the typing from the `install` function:

```js
const install = (app) => {
  components.forEach(component => {
    app.component(component.name, component)
  })
}
```

Remove this line:

```
import type { App } from 'vue'
```